# MSBuild Property Pages Condition

Tags: properties, msbuild, conditional-statements

In my Visual Studio Property file I just wanted to check whether the folder under the given path is existing or not. If that folder is not available in the given path, then it has to make use other set of PropertyGroup Elements(folder under some other path) given.

Comment: What have you tried until now to solve the problem? What did you find in Google? You should put some extra effort before ask for the answer. This is very well documented on MSDN.

Comment: I tried with the following statement:                                       <PropertyGroup Condition= "HasTrailingSlash('$(G:\SK)')"  . Is this correct?

Comment: Whatever you tried should be included in your question.

Comment: Sure... Could you confirm whether the above statement is correct or not.

Comment: I want to help, but I won't do it until you improve your question. Add some exaples, error messages or any additional information that may help people help you. ;)